# Обратная совместимость в .NET CORE

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Как я понял, многое вырезали из .NET CORE в угоду кроссплатформенности.

Например, COM.

Однако, как быть если вдруг будет потребность поработать с office  `Microsoft.Office.Interop`? Или, например, мне потребовалось сделать что-то через WMI.

Ранее можно было сказать:

> Не нужна кроссплатформенность? Пили на .NET Framework

Однако, .NET Framework 4.8 будет [последним](https://medium.com/@andy.watt83/the-net-framework-is-done-8aec3bbae12d) в своем роде, а дальше развиваться будет только .NET CORE => хочешь не хочешь, придется пользоваться .NET CORE если хочешь пользоваться новыми фичами.

Библиотека Interop к .NET CORE подключается, но висит предупреждение, что полная совместимость не гарантируется.

Comment: Поставить рядышком сервис, который умеет в COM и обращаться к нему из core.

Comment: >Библиотека Interop к .NET CORE подключается, но висит предупреждение, что полная совместимость не гарантируется. -- так в этом и соль наверно. Работать будет, но только под виндой например.

Comment: @Monk, на сколько мне известно, обратная совместимость .NET CORE с .NET FRAMEWORK не гарантируется, так как он переписан с 0. Например, там изначально снято ограничение в 255 символов в путях.

Answer (score 4):

COM Interop работает в [.NET Core 2.0+](http://joelleach.net/2018/06/06/com-interop-with-net-core-2-0/). В диалоге добавления ссылки для проектов .NET Core в Visual Studio нет вкладки COM, но можно нажать "Обзор" и указать tlb/dll файл вручную, для него будет корректно сформирована Interop-сборка. Однако, в .NET Core (до версии 3.0) не реализовано позднее связывание (IDispatch), поэтому большая часть функционала Office Automation действительно будет трудно использовать.

**Обновление:** В .NET Core 3.0+ была добавлена поддержка маршаллинга IDispatch (пример можно найти здесь: https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/master/core/extensions/ExcelDemo). Код ниже уже не актуален.

---

Применительно к Excel, к примеру, вот такой код работает:

```
Application app = new Application();
app.Visible = true;

var books = app.Workbooks;
var book = books.Add();
Worksheet sheet = book.ActiveSheet;
Console.WriteLine(sheet.Name);
sheet.Name = "Hello from .NET Core";
```

А вот такой - уже нет:

```
sheet.Cells[1,1] = "Hello from .NET Core"; //ноль эффекта
```

Чтобы задействовать интерфейс Range, использующий позднее связывание, понадобится куда более сложный код:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using ComTypes = System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace NetCoreTest
{ 
    class Program
    {        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            

            Application app = new Application();
            app.Visible = true;

            var books = app.Workbooks;
            var book = books.Add();
            _Worksheet sheet = book.ActiveSheet;

            Range r = sheet.get_Range("A1");
            SetProperty(r, "Value", "Hello from .NET Core");    

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        //Устанавливает свойство COM-объекта с использованием позднего связывания
        public static void SetProperty(object obj, string property, string value)
        {
            int dispId = GetDispId(obj, property); 
            InvokePropertySetter(obj as IDispatch, dispId, value);
        }

        const uint DISPATCH_METHOD = 0x1;
        const uint DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET = 0x2;
        const uint DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT = 0x4;

        // Получение DispId для указанного метода (свойства) COM-объекта с использованием позднего связывания
        // Источник: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/19731
        public static int GetDispId(object rcw, string methodName) 
        {
            IDispatch dispatchObject = rcw as IDispatch;
            if (dispatchObject == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Passed-in argument is not a IDispatch object");
                return -1;
            }

            int[] dispIds = new int[1];
            Guid emtpyRiid = Guid.Empty;
            dispatchObject.GetIDsOfNames(
                emtpyRiid,
                new string[] { methodName },
                1,
                0,
                dispIds);

            if (dispIds[0] == -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Method name {0} cannot be recognized.", methodName);
            }

            return dispIds[0];
        }

        public static object InvokePropertySetter(IDispatch target, int dispId, string val)
        {
            const int DISPID_PROPERTYPUT = -3;
            IntPtr pArg = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr pNamedArgs = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr pStr = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr dispIdArray = IntPtr.Zero, tmpVariants = IntPtr.Zero;

            if (target == null) { Console.WriteLine("Cannot cast target to IDispatch."); return null; }

            try
            {
                pStr = Marshal.StringToBSTR(val);
                Variant variant = new Variant();
                variant.vt = 8; //VT_BSTR
                variant.p = pStr;

                pArg = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(variant));
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(variant, pArg, false);

                pNamedArgs = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(4);
                Marshal.WriteInt32(pNamedArgs, DISPID_PROPERTYPUT);

                var paramArray = new ComTypes.DISPPARAMS[1];
                paramArray[0].rgvarg = pArg;
                paramArray[0].cArgs = 1;
                paramArray[0].cNamedArgs = 1;
                paramArray[0].rgdispidNamedArgs = pNamedArgs;

                ComTypes.EXCEPINFO info = default(ComTypes.EXCEPINFO);
                object result = null;                                
                uint puArgErrNotUsed = 0;

                target.Invoke(dispId, new Guid(), 0x0409, ComTypes.INVOKEKIND.INVOKE_PROPERTYPUT,
                        paramArray, out result, out info, out puArgErrNotUsed);

                return result;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (pStr != IntPtr.Zero) Marshal.FreeBSTR(pStr);
                if (pArg != IntPtr.Zero) Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pArg);
                if (pNamedArgs != IntPtr.Zero) Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pNamedArgs);
            }

        }

        [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
        public static extern int CLSIDFromProgID([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpszProgID, out Guid pclsid);


        [Guid("00020400-0000-0000-c000-000000000046")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        [ComImport]
        public interface IDispatch
        {
            [PreserveSig]
            int GetTypeInfoCount(out int info);

            [PreserveSig]
            int GetTypeInfo(int iTInfo, int lcid, out ComTypes.ITypeInfo ppTInfo);

            void GetIDsOfNames(
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid iid,
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string[] rgszNames,
                int cNames,
                int lcid,
                [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I4)] int[] rgDispId);

            void Invoke(
                int dispIdMember,
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid iid,
                int lcid,
                ComTypes.INVOKEKIND wFlags,
                [In, Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] ComTypes.DISPPARAMS[] paramArray,
                out object pVarResult,
                out ComTypes.EXCEPINFO pExcepInfo,
                out uint puArgErr);
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct Variant
        {
            public ushort vt;
            ushort wReserved1;
            ushort wReserved2;
            ushort wReserved3;
            public IntPtr p;            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А допиливать этот момент microsoft не планирует? И кстати, а что будет если запилить логику на .NET FRAMEWORK, и вызывать ее через .NET CORE? Будет ли работать в таком случае то, что вы описали не работает?

Comment: @iluxa1810 "*А допиливать этот момент microsoft не планирует?*" - Я думаю вряд ли, если бы они хотели это сделать, они бы это сделали сразу. Не то, чтобы это было реальной проблемой, если этот функционал реально нужен, можно просто завернуть свою реализацию IDispatch в реюзабельную библиотеку и подключать ее во все проекты, где он нужен. "*И кстати, а что будет если запилить логику на .NET FRAMEWORK, и вызывать ее через .NET CORE?*" - Через сервис? Можно, но в чем смысл создавать проект для .Net Core и при этом полностью зависеть от .NET Framework.

Comment: Можно, но вроде, intellisense не будет подсказки давать => неудобно с этим работать=(

Comment: "Через сервис?" - не, в отдельную сборку инкапсулировать всю работу с офисом, а потом подключить эту либу в .NET CORE вызвать какой-нибудь спец метод в этой сборке и вся работа с интероптом будет корректно выполнена.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Когда вы добавляете в проект .Net Core ссылку  .NET Framework-сборку, она по сути будет интерпретироваться как .NET Standard (в ней будет работать только то, что работает в обоих платформах). Так что это не решит проблему.

Comment: Эх. Ну надеюсь, что они запилят обратную совместимость, ведь они выпустили какой-то спец. пакет для Net Core https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility . Не то что бы мне нужен COM, но никогда не знаешь, когда оно пригодится=)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте сторонние библиотеки - аналоги.
Например для работы с Office можно работать с тем же [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus)

Кстати, .xlsx -> .zip контейнер с вложенными xml.

Comment: Тем не менее, никакой замены для работы с DAO для Access нету. А так же может быть потребность работы со старым форматом Excel, который не открывается EPPlus.